# Concrete an open hole with water pipes

Tags: concrete

[image: Boiler floor]

I am looking to fill this hole and was hoping someone can guide me as to where to begin!  these are our underfloor heating pipes and I've bought denzo tape to cover them.  do i need to cover the pipes in anything else?  can i concrete straight on top of it all?
Any advice would be greatly welcomed!

Comment: if you only want make it look nice, vacuum out all the construction debris and fill the area with coarse sand or pea gravel

Answer (score 1):

Put a stepped removable wooden grate on top of it, board walk.

Comment: So don’t fill the hole with concrete?

Comment: You may wish to explain your reasoning a bit, as the OP specifically asked about filling the hole with concrete. Why cover it with a grate instead? What advantages / disadvantages does that offer?

Comment: I don't know if I would fill the hole with concrete a board walk may be safer in the long run. Concrete will etch the copper over time being able to access the pipes at a later date may save a lot of time if there is a leak in 10+ years down the road.

Comment: Am happy for any suggestions!  Just seems that any builder who comes and looks at it suggests cementing it?

Comment: Yeah; what Ed said.